# Как проверить открыт ли сейчас файл?.NET

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно првоерить открыт ли сейчас файл в других процессах.

Суть программы не позволяет открывать файлы, которые используются в других процессах. Еще нужно запретить открывать файлы, если он используется в моей программе.

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: См. [FileShare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx): открывай файл со значением `None` - другой процесс не сможет его открыть.

Comment: Чтобы узнать, открыт ли файл в других процессах, можно попытаться его открыть и прочитать/записать/удалить - если что-то не удастся, значит открыт. Но это не сработает, если он открыт другим процессом с `FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напрашивается решение, возвращающее true/false в зависимости от того, открыт файл в стороннем ПО или нет.

Хотелось бы сразу предостеречь от такого подхода: дело в том, что файл может быть и не открыт, но с ним (с файлом) могут быть намного более «интересные» проблемы *(например, этого файла может банально не существовать)*.

В связи с этим вопрос требует более комплексного подхода: так, в примере ниже происходит попытка открытия файла на чтение, и, в случае возникновения ошибки, ее анализ.

**Расширение для Exception** *(конечно, при необходимости легко преобразуется в функцию):*

```
public static class ExceptionExtension
{
  private const int ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION = 32;
  private const int ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION = 33; 

  public static bool IsFileLocked(this Exception exception)
   {
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(exception) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
        return errorCode == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION || errorCode == ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION;
   } 
}
```

**Использование:**

```
     FileStream fs = null;
     try
      {
          fs = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open); // Пробуем открыть файл на чтение
          // ...или сразу читаем содержимое (при необходимости предварительно проверяем файл на размер)
          //byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath); 
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        if (ex.IsFileLocked)
         {
            // Файл открыт в стороннем процессе
            throw;
         }
         else 
         {
           // Произошла иная ошибка доступа к файлу
           throw; 
          }
       }
       finally
       {
         fs?.close();
       }

       // Файл не открыт в стороннем процессе
```

Comment: `ReadAllBytes` - это перебор. По закону подлости там обязательно окажется фильм в формате HD на десятки Гб...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Согласен с вами, немного изменил ответ